# Out of tune and Buzzing

Tags: guitar, intonation

I recently replaced the nut and saddle and put new strings on my acoustic. My guitar does not play in tune, even after I know I've turned it correctly. Some chords sound in tune while others don't.

Frank

Comment: Need a pic of what you've done.

Comment: Hi Frank - the reason pictures would be essential here is that it sounds like you have altered the scale length of the guitar, or in some way messed up the intonation.

Answer (score 1):

A new nut and saddle are essentially new boundary conditions for the string.  Assuming that they are placed correctly on the guitar (pics please) my guess would be that they are no adjusted yet.  The nut grooves may not be low enough and that forces you to press a little harder and will cause the strings to bend out of tune.  This is just a guess.  How much work did you do after the replacement to tweak everything else into proper adjustment?  For example the truss rod may need a tweak.